# How can I compare two shuffled strings?

Tags: javascript

I have the following two strings:

```
var str1 = "hello";
var str2 = "ehlol";
```

How can I check whether both strings contain the same characters?

Comment: Would "hello" and "ehlo" count as a match, given that both are made up of the same four letters?

Comment: "share the same alphabet" is ambiguous, down vote for either not clearly knowing what you want or not clearly specifying it

Comment: In case performance is an issue check my answer for different approach.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

May not be very optimal, but you can simply do

```
str1.split("").sort().join() == str2.split("").sort().join(); //outputs true
```

Another suggested approach in one the comments (for optimization in case string length is quite big)

```
str1.length===str2.length && str1.split("").sort().join() == str2.split("").sort().join(); //first check the length to quickly rule out in case of obvious non-matches
```

Comment: @gurvinder372 will same letters be counter individually?or as one?

Comment: @guradio they will be counted individually

Comment: You could optimise it by first checking length: `str1.length===str2.length && str1.split("").sort().join() == str2.split("").sort().join()`; Longer, but will save you some resource in the easy cases

Comment: Not a JS developer, but what does the .join call achieve here?

Comment: @ymbirtt `str1` is a string, `split` separates it as an array of characters, `sort` reorders the array and finally, `join` concatenates all elements back into one string.

Comment: @ymbirtt, .join will join the elements of the array, in order, into a string to allow for a string comparison rather than an array one.

Comment: @Kroltan, But what's wrong with an array comparison?

Comment: @ymbirtt Arrays with equal contents and lengths are still not equal, because they are reference types. `a=[]; b=[]; a==b //false`, but `a=[];b=a; a==b //true`. However strings are not reference types, so comparing them works. You would have to manually iterate the array with a `for` loop to check their equality.

Comment: @Kroltan, Ah, enlightening, I'd expected it to work like Python and Ruby. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 4):

One of the recommended ways to do it is using a hash table: count how many times each character appears. Note that this works best if your characters are `ASCII`.

The complexity of this algorithm is `O(M+N+sigma)` where `M`, `N` are the lengths of the strings and `sigma` is the number of distinct letters. The complexity of the accepted solution is higher because of the sorting, which is usually done in `O(N*logN)`, but still a good one if your strings are short. If your strings have hundreds of thousands of characters, then this is the way to go. The drawback of using `hash tables` is that the `memory` usage is higher than the solution that uses sorting.

```
function sameLetters(str1, str2){
  var hash = {};

  var len1 = str1.length;
  var len2 = str2.length;

  // Strings with different lengths can't contain the same letters
  if(len1 !== len2) return false;

  // Count how many times each character appears in str1
  for(var i = 0; i < len1; ++i) {
    var c =  str1[i];
    if(typeof hash[c] !== 'undefined') hash[c]++;
    else hash[c] = 1;
  }

  // Make sure each character appearing in str2 was found in str1
  for(var i = 0; i < len2; ++i) {
    var c =  str2[i];
    if(typeof hash[c] === 'undefined') return false;
    if(hash[c] === 0) return false;
    hash[c]--;
  }

  // Make sure no letters are left
  for(var c in hash) {
    if(hash[c]) return false;
  }    

  return true;
}
```

You can then call the function like this (play with it in the browser console):

```
sameLetters("hello", "ehlol"); // true
sameLetters("hello", "ehllol"); // false
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function for this purpose like `sameChars` function here-

```js
function myFunction()
{
    var input_1 = document.getElementById('input_1').value;
    var input_2 = document.getElementById('input_2').value;
    var result = sameChars(input_1,input_2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}

function sameChars(firstStr, secondStr)
{
    var first = firstStr.split('').sort().join('');
    var second = secondStr.split('').sort().join('');
    return first.localeCompare(second)==0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="512" id="input_1"/>
<input type="text" maxlength="512" id="input_2"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check If Shuffled</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Tag is JavaScript, not Java :)

Comment: Sorry, just give me a moment to convert it :(

Comment: It is still java :), try it in your browser console and see

Comment: OK, just a min, I am converting

Comment: Dude, try this, should work, because demo is added with it

Comment: You can just write "return first.localeCompare(second)==0", the equals gives you a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified version of [Gurvinders answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35593856/2025923).

```
var str1 = "hello",
    str2 = "ehlol";

// Add sort on prototype of String object
String.prototype.sort = function () {
    return this.split('').sort().join('');
};

// First check if length of both is same
var same = str1.length === str2.length && str1.sort() === str2.sort();
console.log('Strings are same?', same);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly say this:

```
(a.length === b.length) &&   (a.split('').every(function(val) { return b.indexOf(val) > -1}))
```

And, in ES6 you could make it look as follows:

```
(a.length === b.length) && a.split('').every(val => { return b.indexOf(val) > -1 })
```