# Knockout js compare values

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I need to compare values of variable `name` by `id`. But I do not know ho to do it.

It must be something like:

```
if (this.name == self.copy().indexOf(this.id).name) {
    alert('equals');
} else {
    alert('not equals');
}
```

```js
    function MyViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray();
        self.copy = self.items;
        self.items.push({ id: 1, name: 'Jhon' });
        self.items.push({ id: 2, name: 'Smith' });
        self.alarm = function () {
            alert(this.name);
        }
    }
    
    ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Passenger name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td><input class="target" data-bind="value: name, event: { change: $root.alarm}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can try referring this SO question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593771/how-can-i-compare-two-shuffled-strings/35593911#35593911

Comment: The problem is how to get name by id from ko.observableArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the newer `Array` functions, e.g. `filter`. Use it like this:

```
self.alarm = function(data) {
  var itemsWithSameName = self.copy().filter(function(item) {
    return item.name() === data.name();
  });

  if (itemsWithSameName.length > 0) {
    alert('At least one item with same name exists.');
  } else {
    alert('New name is unique, for now.');
  }
}
```

However, for this to work you need to change `name` on your items `observable` (which is needed anyways for the `value` binding to work).

Also note that I've replaced `this` with `data` as passed to the custom event handler you bound in the view (the "current" item inside the `foreach` is passed as the first arg to `alarm`).

As a final note, beware that `copy` is *not* actually a copy, but a *reference* to the original array.

---

PS. If you want to `filter` by `id` you can do this:

```
self.alarm = function(data) {
  var itemsWithSameId = self.copy().filter(function(item) {
    return item.id === data.id;
  });

  // If `id` is guaranteed to be unique, you can probably get away
  // with just assuming/grabbing the only item found:
  var theItem = itemsWithSameId[0];

  // Note that you've just essentially retrieved `data`. That is:
  // data === theItem

  if (!!theItem) {
    alert('At least one item with same id exists.');
  } else {
    alert('Id of edited item cuold not be found.');
  }
}
```

As I've put in comments, this makes less sense, because `data` passed to the event handler already *is* a reference to the item from your `observableArray`.